# Integral of measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a measurable set with finite measure $m(E) < \infty$. Let $f_n: E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ almost everywhere in $E$. Prove that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_E \frac{f_n(x)}{1+f_n(x)}dx = \int_E \frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}dx.$$
I'm trying to prove this equality in preparation for an exam of real analysis. I would appreciate your help in solving this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$$
\frac{f_n(x)}{1+f_n(x)} \leq 1,
$$
and since $m(E)<\infty$ we can pass to the limit (why?)

Comment: I believe we can pass to the limit by the bounded convergence theorem. Thanks for the hint.